# Java: How to read through file.txt and replace line breaks with a special key word

Tags: java, regex, newline, reader

I would like to read through a text file such as:

> The letters herein by Lincoln are so thoroughly characteristic of
>   the man, and are in themselves so completely self-explanatory, that
>   it requires no comment to enable the reader fully to understand and
>   appreciate them. It will be observed that the philosophical
>   admonitions in the letter to his brother, Johnston, were written on
>   the same sheet with the letter to his father.
>
> The promptness and decision with which Lincoln despatched the
>   multitudinous affairs of his office during the most turbulent
>   scenes of the Civil War are exemplified in his unequivocal order to
>   the Attorney-General, indorsed on the back of the letter of Hon.
>   Austin A. King, requesting a pardon for John B. Corner. The
>   indorsement bears even date with the letter itself, and Corner was
>   pardoned on the following day.

and replace every line breaker with a special key character. 
Afterwards I am going to create char[] arr and insert each and every character of this two paragraphs into the char[] array.

```
public void readFile (String aFileName) {

    String file = aFileName;
    String line = null; // string to read line by line

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);

            if (line.matches("\r\n")) {
                System.out.println("it has");
            }
            if (line.matches("\n")) {
                System.out.println("bu");
            }
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file " + file + "!");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using to read through the text.txt file. The idea is to check whether a line of text has a line breaker and then I would like to replace it.

Unfortunately, this method does not recognize any line breakers. For instance, in the text above: After "with the letter to his father." by the end of the first paragraph there is new line but the reader does not recognize it.

Please, any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For matches to be true, the *whole line* has to match. That's not what you want. Regardless, you're already getting line breaks through the readLine method!

Comment: s/java/[python|perl|scala|anything else]/g

Answer (score 0):

`readLine()` *removes* the line terminator. See the Javadoc. All you have to do is append to each line.